# using python 'with' statement with iterators?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.5. I'm trying to use this 'with' statement.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
a = []
with open('exampletxt.txt','r') as f:
    while True:
        a.append(f.next().strip().split())
print a
```

The contents of 'exampletxt.txt' are simple:

```
a
b
```

In this case, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/python-7036sVf.py", line 5, in <module>
    a.append(f.next().strip().split())
StopIteration
```

And if I replace `f.next()` with `f.read()`, it seems to be caught in an infinite loop.

I wonder if I have to write a decorator class that accepts the iterator object as an argument, and define an `__exit__` method for it?

I know it's more pythonic to use a for-loop for iterators, but I wanted to implement a while loop within a generator that's called by a for-loop... something [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264504/processing-text-from-a-non-flat-file-to-extract-information-as-if-it-were-a-fl)

```
def g(f):
    while True:
        x = f.next()
        if test1(x):
            a = x
        elif test2(x):
            b = f.next()
            yield [a,x,b]

a = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for x in g(f):
        a.append(x)
```

Comment: nothing to do with `with` ... ?

Comment: yes, appears so. i thought the 'with' statement provided an alternative form for exception handling but i guess not in this way.

Comment: Thanks, but it really was a question of applicability of the with statement in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising `StopIteration` is what an iterator does when it gets to the end. Normally the `for` statement catches it silently and continues to the `else` clause, but if it's being iterated manually as in your case then the code has to be prepared to handle the exception itself.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I thought the 'with' statement was supposed to handle that exception as well, but guess not...

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop doesn't end, but the file does so it raises a StopIteration exception when there is nothing else to iterate to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any terminating condition in any of your while loops, so you keep returning until you get StopIteration exception which you don't handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can always rewrite while-with-explicit-next loops.  When you have an explicit `next`, you're just looking ahead one token.

Generally, loops of this form can be rewritten.

```
def g(f):
    while True:
        x = f.next()
        if test1(x):
            a = x
        elif test2(x):
            b = f.next()
            yield [a,x,b]
```

You can always replace a look-ahead `next` by buffering a value.

```
def g(f):
    prev, a = None, None
    for x in f:
        if test2(prev)
            yield [ a, prev, x ]
        elif test1(x):
            a = x
        prev= x
```

Comment: Thank you - looks like the for-loop is the way to go in handling these iterators.